# Finding emperical variance in list of multiple realizations of random vector

Tags: r

I have have created a list of 1000 realizations of a random vector by using the following command:

> replicate(1000, matrix( rnorm(1*10,mean=0,sd=1), 1, 10) )

I then want to find the emperical variance of each realization. I have tried to use the "var" function on my simulated data, but i get an error telling me my input is not atomic.
Can anyone help with a smart solution?

Comment: For future reference, you'll make it much easier for people to answer your questions if you post all of the code related to your problem and the exact text of the error message you received.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I will keep that in mind for the next time I post a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without creating a 3D array. Here's a small example:

```
# 3 realizations of a random vector
set.seed(1)
x = replicate(3, rnorm(5,mean=0,sd=1) )

           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] -0.6264538 -0.8204684  1.5117812
[2,]  0.1836433  0.4874291  0.3898432
[3,] -0.8356286  0.7383247 -0.6212406
[4,]  1.5952808  0.5757814 -2.2146999
[5,]  0.3295078 -0.3053884  1.1249309
```

`apply` applies a function to each column (in this case) or row of a matrix or data frame. In this case we apply the `var` function to each column of the matrix `x`. To apply by row, set `MARGIN` to 1 instead of 2.

```
# Calculate variance of each random vector
apply(x, 2, var)

[1] 0.9235968 0.4473392 2.2466246
```